# what would be an efficient way to rank the top 3 co2 datas?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting, ranking

how can I make use of Numpy to rank the top 3 co2 data with the year? the image below shows what I have got so far, I am able to zip them together but I am not quite sure on how to sort and print the top 3 without messing with the indexes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIsQq.png

Answer (score 0):

With python's standard library: [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest)

```py
from heapq import nlargest

c = [2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]
x = [10., 9.57, 9.27, 9.32, 9.72, 9.65]

for v,y in nlargest(3, zip(x,c)):
    print('Year: {};  CO2: {}'.format(y,v))
# Year: 2013;  CO2: 10.0
# Year: 2017;  CO2: 9.72
# Year: 2018;  CO2: 9.65
```

With numpy: [`numpy.argpartition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html)

```py
import numpy as np

cx = np.array([[2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018],
               [10., 9.57, 9.27, 9.32, 9.72, 9.65]])

idx_top3 = np.argpartition(cx, (-3,-2,-1))

cx_top3 = cx[:, idx_top3[1,-3:]]

print(cx_top3)
# [[2018.   2017.   2013.  ]
#  [   9.65    9.72   10.  ]]
```

See also: [`pandas.DataFrame.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html)

Comment: btw, possible to explain the " cx_top3 = cx[:, idx_top3[1,-3:]] "
tried playing around but unsure about the "1,-3" and ":"

Comment: @QWERTY_ There might be a better way to use `argpartition` than the way I did. Since nothing in the arguments I passed to `argpartition` specifies that we're interested in the top 3 `x`-values, as opposed to the top 3 `c`-values (which would be the three most recent years), `argpartition` returned an array with two rows: one row with indices indicating the top 3 `x`-values and one row inticating the top 3 `c`-values. `idx_top3[1,-3:]` means "we want the last three values of row 1". Here row 0 is the years and row 1 is the co2 values.

Comment: @QWERTY_ Then the `:` in `cx[:, ...]` mean we want both rows of `cx`. If instead I had written `cx[0, idx_top3[1,-3:]]` we would only have gotten the years, and if I had written `cx[1, idx_top3[1,-3:]]` we would only have gotten the co2 values.

Comment: @QWERTY_ Hi! Apparently you unaccepted the answer today. Did something go wrong?